# algorithm/formula to move elements so they reach a specific x and y coordinate at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, scroll, position

i want to move an div to 70% left and 10% top of my viewport when i scroll. My Code for that is here:

```
Flower.prototype.animateToKeyframe = function() {
    var scroll = window.pageYOffset / window.innerHeight * 100;

    // check if next keyframe needs to be loaded
    if (!this.animationDone) { 
        // var formula = (this.initialPos.top - this.keyframe['top'] * percentHeight) / (this.initialPos.left - this.keyframe['left'] * percentWidth) * (scroll * 5);

        /*
        *  Animating top position
        */
        if (this.pos.top > percentHeight * this.keyframe['top']) { 
            this.domEl.css('top', (this.initialPos.top - (scroll * this.speed)) + 'px');
        } else if (this.pos.top < percentHeight * this.keyframe['top']) {
            this.domEl.css('top', (this.initialPos.top + (scroll * this.speed)) + 'px');
        }

        /*
        *  Animating left position
        */
        if (this.pos.left < percentWidth * this.keyframe['left']) { 
            this.domEl.css('left', (this.initialPos.left + (scroll * this.speed)) + 'px');
        } else if (this.pos.left > percentWidth * this.keyframe['left']) {
            this.domEl.css('left', (this.initialPos.left - (scroll * this.speed)) + 'px');
        }

        /*
        *  Animating rotation
        */
        this.domEl.css('transform', 'rotateZ(' + (this.rotation + (scroll * this.speed)) + 'deg)');
        this.domEl.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ(' + (this.rotation + (scroll * this.speed)) + 'deg)');
        /*
        * updating and checking position
        */
        this.pos = this.domEl.position();
        var leftDone = this.pos.left > (percentWidth * this.keyframe['left'] - 5) && this.pos.left < (percentWidth * this.keyframe['left'] + 5);
        var topDone = this.pos.top > (percentHeight * this.keyframe['top'] - 5) && this.pos.top < (percentHeight * this.keyframe['top'] + 5);

        if (topDone && leftDone) {
            alert('fertig!' + this.num);
            this.animationDone = true;
        }
    } else {
        this.getKeyframe();
    }
```

this.keyframe is an object: {left: 70, top: 10, rotation: 100}. But when i scroll, the element is moving along the x and y axis equally. However i want both css-styles to move that way that they both reach the target (this.keyframe) at the same time. Otherwise it arrives first on the y-axis and later on the x-axis.

I tried to realize that with linear equation as you can see here:
    // var formula = (this.initialPos.top - this.keyframe['top'] * percentHeight) / (this.initialPos.left - this.keyframe['left'] * percentWidth) * (scroll * 5);

However i can't put that into the code changing the top position AND the left position because it would move equally again then.

Do you have any Idea for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with lerp-ing now. Thanks however!

```
    var stopPosition = (1 / this.keyframe['stop'] * scroll) - (this.keyframeIndex - 1);

    // lerp-ing through position animation
    var formulaX = this.initialPos.left + stopPosition * (xTarget - this.initialPos.left);
    var formulaY = this.initialPos.top + stopPosition * (yTarget - this.initialPos.top);


    /*
    *  Animating positions
    */
    this.domEl.css('top', (formulaY) + 'px');
    this.domEl.css('left', (formulaX) + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the same effect - the movement is not linear - but when I have to move an object to a target position, I use continuous linear interpolation, like:

```
for( ;; /* every frame */ ) {
    if( Math.abs( current.x - target.x ) < 0.1 ) {
        done();
    } else {
        current.x = current.x * 0.9 + target.x * 0.1;
        current.y = current.y * 0.9 + target.y * 0.1;
        current.a = current.a * 0.9 + target.a * 0.1;
    }
}
```

It will reach the destination at the same time on both axes.

If you still want linear movement, your approach is ok, but you have to calculate the speed for every variable (every axis).